# HTTP GET What is significance of slash before filename in request line?

Tags: http, request

I'm researching more into HTTP Headers at the moment as it's something I've wanted to brush up on for a while now. When you create the request line (example: GET /index.php HTTP/1.1) What is significance of slash before filename in request line?

I know that GET is a 'method', the filename is the 'path' and the HTTP/1.1 is the 'protocol' but why do we need the slash before filename in request line?

Comment: I would suspect it's an absolute path.  Hence, `/index,php` means "the index page in the root directory".  Note that this is the root directory relevant to the web server, not the machine itself.  For example, apache's default root dir is /var/www.  I believe it is called the `DocumentRoot`

Comment: Ah I see, so the “/” before the filename signifies the server root. I got it, thank you for your answer, much appreciated.

Comment: That's my guess.  I don't know for sure, but a good way to check would be to GET a file that's in a subdirectory.